# Retrieve JSON encoded data in AJAX callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the result when I do console.log(data) within my AJAX callback

```
{"image":"http://placehold.it/290x120","url":"http://www.google.com.my"}
```

but when I do `data['image']` or `data['url']`, it can't retrieve the value correctly. I also tried `data[0]['image']` to no avail

Comment: Please show me the result of console.log(typeof data). I guess your  data variable is a string type

Comment: @wander oh it's a string! how come?

Comment: Have you parsed the JSON string? Something like `var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);`

Answer (score 2):

So I guess data is returned from a ajax request. Your can use the following code to convert string to object:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

If you are using jQuery to do the ajax request, you can add `dataType: "json"` to the ajax option. In this way, there's no need to convert data.

Answer (score 1):

Your data in callback is JSON Object,then

var image=data.image;
var url=data.url;

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `data.image` and `data.url`?
also try `var x = eval(data);`
then `x.image` and `x.url`

Be careful of `eval()` on untrusted data though!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse it to Json

```
var retrieved = ......;
var json = JSON.parse(retrieved);
```

and then just use:

```
var image = json.image;
var url = json.url;
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are getting string as a response then use like below.

```
var response = '{"image":"http://placehold.it/290x120","url":"http://www.google.com.my"}';
var data = eval("("+response +")");
console.log(data["image"]);
console.log(data["url"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usualy this code from jQuery API's [page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) works great:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

> The success callback is passed the returned data, which is typically a JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed using the $.parseJSON() method. It is also passed the text status of the response.

However, you must remember about the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) as well as the about the correct server response's content type. For json response it should be `application/x-javascript` or at least `text/json`.

Answer (score 0):

javascript does not have associative arrays, You should use a javascript object like

`var data = JSON.parse(data)`

and then you can acces it by

`data.image` and `data.url`

Comment: However accessing an object property with brackets work and is a big advantage when dealing with variable property names.

Comment: where's the advantage? i'm not saying you're wrong, i'm just curious what you mean. I assumed it was bad practice because it officially doesn't exist

Comment: if the object key is created dynamically, you'll need the brackets to get the value. For example : `var key = lname+fname; alert(person[key]);` will work, but not : `alert(person.key)`